# Zend gdata calendar-looking for event created and event edited elements

Tags: zend-framework, gdata

I'm having a touch time finding the data from the Zend Gdata feed that gives me:

- The date that the event was created
- The date of the most recent edit to the event

I'm hoping to find these variables in a form similar to how I get the event ID:

```
pr($event->id->text);
```

I'm sure it is documents, and if anyone can point me to a chart of all the elements available in the feed, that would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah-got it:

```
  pr($event->published->text);  //when event was first published
  pr($event->updated->text);    //when event was last updated.
```

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/elements.html